# Display the fields dynamically after clicking on add more fields button

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I added the custom fields in the WordPress admin panel I added a button called Add more fields so that users can add more than one. Now my issue is, I have to display fields dynamically by clicking on the `Add more fields` button.

I tried the below code but when I click on the `Add more fields` button then I am getting the browser warning and clicking on the leave button page then the page refreshed.

What is the issue with my code?

[image]

Full code here

```
function woocommerce_register_2col_layout_fields() {
    global $post;
    // Nonce field to validate form request came from current site
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'layout' );
    // Output the field
    echo '<button id="addMore_layout">Add more fields</button>';
    echo '<div class="create_custom_layout" id="create_custom_layout"><div class="row">';
        echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
            echo '<h4>Description</h4>';
            //We first get the post_meta from the DB if there's any there.
            $description        = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pDescription', true );
            //Second ID the field.
            $description_field  = 'pDescription';
            //Provide the settings arguments for this specific editor in an array
            $description_args   = array( 'media_buttons' => false, 'textarea_rows' => 12, 'textarea_name' => 'pDescription[]',
            'editor_class' => 'description-editor widefat', 'wpautop' => true );
            wp_editor( $description, $description_field, $description_args );
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>Banner image</h4>
            <input type="button" id="meta-image-button" class="button" value="Choose or Upload an Image" style="padding: 8px 10px; height: auto; line-height: normal;"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="pimage[]" id="meta-image" class="meta_image" value="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pimage', true ).'" /><br />
            <img style="width: 100px;height: 100px;object-fit: cover;" id="meta-image-preview" src="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pimage', true ).'" />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .create_custom_layout .row{display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;}
    .create_custom_layout .col-md-6 {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>
<script>
    jQuery("#meta-image-button").click(function() {
        var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
        wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {
    jQuery("#meta-image").val(attachment.url);
        jQuery("#meta-image-preview").attr("src",attachment.url);
            wp.media.editor.send.attachment = send_attachment_bkp;
        }
        wp.media.editor.open();
        return false;
    });

  jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#addMore_layout").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery("#create_custom_layout").append("
    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><h4>Description</h4>';
            //We first get the post_meta from the DB if there's any there.
            $description        = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pDescription', true );
            //Second ID the field.
            $description_field  = 'pDescription';
            //Provide the settings arguments for this specific editor in an array
            $description_args   = array( 'media_buttons' => false, 'textarea_rows' => 12, 'textarea_name' => 'pDescription[]',
            'editor_class' => 'description-editor widefat', 'wpautop' => true );
            wp_editor( $description, $description_field, $description_args );
        '</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>Banner image</h4>
            <input type="button" id="meta-image-button" class="button" value="Choose or Upload an Image" style="padding: 8px 10px; height: auto; line-height: normal;"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="pimage[]" id="meta-image" class="meta_image" value="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pimage', true ).'" /><br />
            <img style="width: 100px;height: 100px;object-fit: cover;" id="meta-image-preview" src="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pimage', true ).'" />

        </div>
    </div>
    ");
  });
});

</script>';
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you add this line inside your button i.e : `type="button"` ?

Comment: @Swati, Now the page not refreshing. Is there any issue with the script? because when I click it's not adding the fields

Comment: I cannot run that it has wp code as well. But , put console inside your event handler see if that's getting printing .. then try with some custom data `jQuery("#create_custom_layout").append("somethingg....")` see if this gets appended . Also , check browser console see if there are any errors.

Comment: I added the alert to check and I am getting my alert by clicking then I added    jQuery("#create_custom_layout").append("<div class="row"></div>">)
 but that;s not displaying

Comment: Are you seeing any error inside browser console ? That simple line should work .

Comment: @Swati, Yes, I am getting the Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. I am using only this <script>
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#addMore_layout").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("alert");
   jQuery("#create_custom_layout").append("<div class="row"></div>");
   alert("alert2");
   console.log("hello");
   
  })
});
</script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227757/discussion-between-swati-and-user9437856).